# Can Crystal Reports generate documents in PDF/A file format?

Tags: crystal-reports, pdf-generation, pdfa

We are looking for a solution to generate documents in [PDF/A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A) format for sharing and also archiving purpose.

I checked the description of [ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms226443%28VS.90%29.aspx), however it just say PDF file.

Can the Crystal Reports generate PDF/A compatible files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you export directly to PDF/A.  Instead, I recommend using Crystal to export to PDF, then find a third-party software to convert your PDF to PDF/A. It takes 1 extra step, but it will meet your needs.

I googled a bit and found http://www.abbyyusa.com/shop/pdftransformer/.  I know nothing about this software, I'm just presenting it as an example.  It costs 80USD, but you might be able to find a freeware alternative.

http://www.pdfa.org/doku.php is the offical homepage of PDF/A.  You might find something useful there too.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this SAP community thread](http://forums.sdn.sap.com/thread.jspa?messageID=9607676&tstart=0) from a few days ago, it can't be done natively, although there was a third-party component mentioned there.  I haven't tried it, so I have no idea if it works or not.